# Scala - why cannot use trait from object

Tags: scala

I have created a simple application with singleton object which contains local traits:

```
object Singleton {

  trait FirstTrait {
    val func1 = (i: Int) => i * 2
  }

  trait SecondTrait {
    val func2 = (s: String) => s
  }

  trait ThirdTrait {
    val func3 = () => println("Func 3")
  }
}
```

And now, in `Main` object, I would like to do something like this:

```
object Main extends App {    
  val singleton = Singleton.FirstTrait//cannot do this
}
```

But I cannot do this (compile error). Why? Why I have not an access into this local trait? If I change `Singleton` object into:

```
object Singleton {

  trait FirstTrait {
    val func1 = (i: Int) => i * 2
  }

  trait SecondTrait {
    val func2 = (s: String) => s
  }

  trait ThirdTrait {
    val func3 = () => println("Func 3")
  }

  object FirstObject extends FirstTrait {
    println(func1)
  }
}
```

`Main` works well and program compiles. But I call another singleton object from `Singleton`, not a trait. I understand that `trait` cannot be instanced, but I think it is not a solution for it, because I have also a simple `ScalaTest` test name, which looks like

```
"Singleton" should "test it" in Singleton.FirstTrait{...}
```

and here I have an access into `FirstTrait`. So why I cannot use it in normal code?
I cannot understand it well. Maybe I am an idiot, but if someone could explain it to me well, I would be greatful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `trait` so you'll need to "instantiate" it properly:

```
val singleton = new Singleton.FirstTrait {}
// singleton: Singleton.FirstTrait = $anon$1@5e97da56
```

Note that technically a `trait` cannot be instantiated.  The above expression is an instantiation of the anonymous class that extends the trait.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So in Scala the `trait` can be instantiate like normal `class`? `new` keyword and `object` in one are not logical for me. Could you tell more?

Comment: That's right, and since it's a `trait` you'll need to implement its abstract members, if any.  Here's a relevant [link](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-trait-examples) which might be of interest.

Comment: Not quite, this isn't instantiating the trait, but an anonymous class extending the trait.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov, good point.  It's indeed an instantiation of the anonymous class that extends the trait.

Answer (score 1):

`Singleton.FirstTrait` is a type, not a value. You can't write

```
val singleton = Singleton.FirstTrait
```

any more than you can write

```
val singleton = Int
val singleton = String
```

etc. Traits and classes can have companion objects (`object`s with the same name), but `FirstTrait` obviously doesn't have one.

You *can* use it as a type, e.g.

```
def foo(x: Singleton.FirstTrait) = {}
val x: Singleton.FirstTrait = new Singleton.FirstTrait {}
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. So in my second example I have an companion object for a `trait` so I can use it like a value.

Comment: It's just an object (not a companion object because it's called `FirstObject`, not `FirstTrait`), and you can use any object as a value.